# For the below program , i want to print duplicate element which is 5,6,1 but when array is having some no 3 times its not providing correct output

Tags: java

For the below program , i want to print duplicate element which is 5,6,1 but when array is having same no 3 times its not providing correct output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            int[] data = {5, 6, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5,6};
    
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    
            ArrayList<Integer> dup = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int index = 0; index < data.length; index++){
                if(dup.contains(data[index])){
                    System.out.println("Duplicate Element : " + data[index]);
                } else {
                    dup.add(data[index]);
                }
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please include the actual and expected output IN the question. Use a question title that summarizes your problem ...instead of lengthy text.

Comment: This code works for me: it outputs 6, 5, 1, 5, 6

Comment: But output i expect is duplicate values alone like 6,5,1

Comment: Then it is probably easiest for you to use a `Set` for your duplicates.

Comment: Modify the question part and include an example that gives the current output (which you say as wrong) and also the expected output for that example.

Comment: Then you may keep a second collection of type Set<Integer>, and store your duplicates in it. Only print "Duplicate element" when the integer was not yet in the set . Easy to check as Set.add() returns a boolean indicating it was already in the set or not.

Comment: ok input is :{5, 6, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5,6}, output=5,6,1

Answer (score 4):

You can use this solution:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = {5, 6, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5,6};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

    Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> duplicatesToShow = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(int index = 0; index < data.length; index++){
      if(duplicates.contains(data[index])){
        duplicatesToShow.add(data[index]);
      } else {
        duplicates.add(data[index]);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Duplicate Element : " + duplicatesToShow.toString());

  }
```

We need to collections: one for tracking the duplicates (`duplicates`) and one for showing later the duplicates (`duplicatesToShow`). We use `Set` as this collections holds only unique elements and no duplicates.

Running this code yields:

```
[5, 6, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6]
Duplicate Element : [6, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to retain the order, you can just use sets.

```
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>(List.of(5, 6, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6));

Set<Integer> noDupes = new HashSet(data); // items without dupes
data.removeAll(noDupes); // data now contains only dupes
Set<Integer> dupes = new HashSet(data); // dupes without repetition
```